# jQuery Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLDivElement]

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I am looping through a set of elements and then I am trying to find some specific children of said element in the loop at that time, but I am getting an error.

My code:

```
var submenu_height;
var secondary_submenus;
var secondary_submenu_height;

// Get the submenus
var submenus = $('#main section.top nav > ul > li > .sub_menu');

// Now loop through each submenu

submenus.each(function(i, element) {

    // Get height of submenu
    submenu_height = $(this).height();

    // Reset our secondary submenu height
    secondary_submenu_height = 0;

    // Get submenus of this submenu
    secondary_submenus = $(this + ' table.sm_wrapper td ul li .sm_wrapper2');



});
```

The problem lies in this line:

```
secondary_submenus = $(this + ' table.sm_wrapper td ul li .sm_wrapper2');
```

I tried using `element` as well as `this` but neither worked. The error I am getting is:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLDivElement] table.sm_wrapper td ul li .sm_wrapper
```

What is the correct way to do what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want

```
secondary_submenus = $(this).find('table.sm_wrapper td ul li .sm_wrapper2');
```

The reason you were getting an error is because you were attempting to add an object(`this`) to a string and use it as a selector, hence

> ...**unrecognized expression**: [object HTMLDivElement]...

What [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) will do is search the children from the context of `$(this)` for the mentioned elements in the passed selector

Comment: Ahhhh, yeah, I thought that may have been my problem lol. Thanks for the code on how to do it.